# How to interrupt Console.In.ReadLine in .Net?

Tags: .net

I have a console app which reads lines infinitely with Console.In.ReadLine() on one thread and sends them for processing to other threads through an IObservable (Reactive Extensions).

When the application has to close I want to close the input stream with Console.In.Close() from a second thread and expect an IOException in the first thread.

The problem is that after running Console.In.Close() the ReadLine call is not interrupted.

Why doesn't this work? How can I interrupt the ReadLine?

Comment: Are you talking about [ReadLine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: Chicked-and-egg problem, Console.In.Close() is going to deadlock while any read is in progress.  Setting the thread's IsBackground property to true ought to be a simple fix.

Comment: I'm using Console.In.ReadLine() (Console.In is a TextReader and has a ReadLine method)

Comment: ...and there is no deadlock. Console.In.Close runs apparently OK but there is no visible effect i.e. Console.In.ReadLine is not interrupted as I would expect